# Nested IFNA in array Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the below code. The Course Name, Delivery and Completion Date mismatches work as expected. However I am trying to implement one final row for email mismatch. If the email can't be found in the "another google sheet" I want it to return E-mail mismatch, but it looks as though the iferror is suppressing it. Thoughts/Help?

Thank you in advance.

```
 =ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(C:C)=1, "Unverified Reason", 
IF(ISNA(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),1,0)),"E-Mail Mismatch",
IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),4,0))<>LOWER(I:I),"Course Name Mismatch",
IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),5,0))<>LOWER(T:T),"Delievery Method MisMatch",
IF(TO_DATE(INT(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),3,0)))<>F:F,"Completion Date Mismatch",""))))))))
```

EDIT: I got what I needed by using the following.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(C:C)=1, "Unverified Reason", 
if(A:A="","",
IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),4,0))<>LOWER(I:I),"Course Name Mismatch",
IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),5,0))<>LOWER(T:T),"Delivery Method MisMatch",
IF(TO_DATE(INT(VLOOKUP(C:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),3,0)))<>F:F,"Completion Date Mismatch",""))))),"Potential E-Mail Mismatch"))
```

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Unverified Reason"; 
 IF(IFNA(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C2:C, IMPORTRANGE("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),1,)), "E-Mail Mismatch"),
 IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C2:C,IMPORTRANGE("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),4,))<>LOWER(I:I), "Course Name Mismatch",
 IF(LOWER(VLOOKUP(C2:C,IMPORTRANGE("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),5,))<>LOWER(T:T), "Delievery Method MisMatch",
 IF(TO_DATE(INT(VLOOKUP(C2:C,importrange("anothergooglesheet","Course Completion!B:F"),3,)))<>F:F, "Completion Date Mismatch",))))})
```